# set datatable first row as grid header

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a scenario where i am fetching data from xls file using following connection string

```
mCon.ConnectionString = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=" + mstrFilePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=NO\";");
```

and following code

```
string strSelectQuery = "Select * from [sheet1$]";    
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand= new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(strSelectQuery, mCon);
DataAdapter = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strSelectQuery, mCon);
DataAdapter.Fill(mDTable);
```

Now when i bind this datatable mDtable to gridview, It results in no header row for grid.

But i have another gridview which needs to have header columns as the first row in datatable mDTable.

How can i use same datatable to bind both gridview's one without header row and another with header row ??

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259897/how-to-make-the-first-row-of-the-datatable-as-my-datagrid-header-asp-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Harsh solution:

You can sign the column header, using DataTable.Columns[n].ColumnName.

Example (not tested, beware of code error):

```
int index = 0;
foreach(DataTableColumn col in DataTable.Columns)
{
  col.ColumnName = DataTable.Rows[0][index].ToString();
  index++;
}
```

Then you can bind the DataTable to gridview, and set AutoGenerateColumn to true.