# Delete DataTable header

Tags: c#, .net

I have a DataTable1 with a bunch of rows that I have imported from Excel. Row 1 of this Excel sheet contains data that is not relevant to my application. When I import this sheet to DataTable1, that first row becomes the header.
**What I am trying to accomplish:** *Delete* the header row so that when I clone DataTable1 to DataTable2, the second row (formerly third, before the deletion) of DataTable1 is the header of DataTable2. I am not trying to *hide* the header of DataTable1 - I am trying to *delete* it completely without having to delete it manually in Excel. This header/cell will always be identifiable, because in the Excel sheet, the value of that very first cell is literally, "Unnecessary Data".
**So, for example:**
Unnecessary Data | Unnecessary Data | Unnecessary Data | Unnecessary Data
       Column 1        |       Column 2         |       Column 3         |
       Column 3       
           Stuff            |
           Stuff            |
           Stuff            |
           Stuff            |
           Stuff            |
           Stuff            |
           Stuff            |
           Stuff            |
           Stuff            |
           Stuff            |
           Stuff            |
           Stuff            |
           Stuff            |
           Stuff            |
           Stuff            |
           Stuff            |
           Stuff            |
           Stuff            |
           Stuff            |
           Stuff            |

**Would become:**
       Column 1        |       Column 2         |       Column 3         |
       Column 3       
           Stuff            |
           Stuff            |
           Stuff            |
           Stuff            |
           Stuff            |
           Stuff            |
           Stuff            |
           Stuff            |
           Stuff            |
           Stuff            |
           Stuff            |
           Stuff            |
           Stuff            |
           Stuff            |
           Stuff            |
           Stuff            |
           Stuff            |
           Stuff            |
           Stuff            |
           Stuff            |



I did a bunch of Googling and brain storming and I cannot figure out how to accomplish this.

I have tried:

```
if (DataTable1.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "Unnecessary Data")
{
    DataTable2 = DataTable1.Clone();
    DataTable2.Rows.Remove(DataTable1.Rows[0]);
}
```

Which does not work because Row[0] is actually the first row after my header.

```
if (DataTable1.Rows[0][-1].ToString() == "Unnecessary Data")
{
    DataTable2 = DataTable1.Clone();
    DataTable2.Rows.Remove(DataTable1.Rows[0]);
}
```

Does not work either because -1 is not an index. Can anyone help?

Comment: Possibly solves your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/q/15492589/1578604 You could set the headers from the row you need it from first, then delete that row when you are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the aim is using the values of the second row to set the columns names of `dataTable1`, and getting rid of the first and second rows:

```cs
dataTable1.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(c => c.ColumnName = dataTable1.Rows[1][c.Ordinal].ToString());

dataTable1.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
dataTable1.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
```

However, if you need to keep the `dataTable1` as is and create a new DataTable:

```cs
var dataTable2 = dataTable1.AsEnumerable().Skip(2).CopyToDataTable();

dataTable2.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(c => c.ColumnName = dataTable1.Rows[1][c.Ordinal].ToString());
```

[image: SOA62543559]

Comment: Hey - I'm getting a 'ColumnName' is required when it is part of a DataTable error for each of these examples :/

Comment: Still get the same exception, but dataTable1 absolutely has values. Checked with this line of code to make sure: dataTable1.Rows[0].ItemArray.Aggregate(string.Empty, (b, s) => string.IsNullOrEmpty(b) ? $"[{s}]" : $"{b}, [{s}]")

Comment: The second method was incorrect. Use this to produce what you see if that is your aim. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I built this example, there is no need to clone anything, hope it helps:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Test");
dt.Rows.Add("1");
dt.Rows.Add("2");
dt.Rows.Add("3");

dt.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
dt.Rows.RemoveAt(0);

// contains "3"
var test = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0];
```

If you want the second line to become header, I would do something like this, just not sure what your type situation is:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Test");
dt.Rows.Add("1");
dt.Rows.Add("2");
dt.Rows.Add("3");

dt.Rows.RemoveAt(0);

var i = 0;
foreach(var col in dt.Rows[0].ItemArray)
{
    dt.Columns[i].ColumnName = col.ToString();
    i++;
}
dt.Rows.RemoveAt(0);

// contains "3"
var test = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0];
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks. Tested this - I see how this would work in theory. However, for the line, dt.Columns[i].ColumnName = col.ToString();, I get an error: 'ColumnName is required when it is part of a DataTable.'

Comment: I would guess the Row you are trying to substitute as new column names has a NULL in it or perhaps just empty string.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought too - I double checked - it's not null or empty :(.

Comment: Try to run this on the row that's supposed to be a header: var test = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray.Aggregate(string.Empty, (b, s) => string.IsNullOrEmpty(b) ? $"[{s}]" : $"{b}, [{s}]"); and post it, should give us better idea.

Comment: It's showing my the first row (not the column headers).

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough detail about how you get your DataTable imported from excel file and I'm not even sure that the DataTable you are using is DataTable from `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` or from `System.Data`

If you make sure that your DataTable is converted to the DataTable of `System.Data` namespace, your problem will be fixed by this piece of code:

```
DataTable.Rows[rowIndex].Delete();
```

As you can see it done in following example:

```
        //create a DataTable
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

        //Add Columns for DataTable
        dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("First Column"));
        dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Second Column"));

        //Add redundant DataRow and another DataRow to DataTable
        DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
        dataRow[0] = "_";
        dataRow[1] = "Redundant Row";
        dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
        dataRow[0] = "1";
        dataRow[1] = "First Row";
        dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);


        //print out the DataTable before deleting redundant DataRow
        Console.WriteLine("\n" + dataTable.Columns[0] + "\t" + dataTable.Columns[1] + "\n");
        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(row[0] + "\t\t" + row[1]);
        }

        //delete redundant DataRow
        dataTable.Rows[0].Delete();

        //print again the DataSet to see results
        Console.WriteLine("\n" + dataTable.Columns[0] + "\t" + dataTable.Columns[1] + "\n");
        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(row[0] + "\t\t" + row[1]);
        }
```

The result of code after execution is:

Before `dataTable.Rows[0].Delete();` executes:

```
First Column    Second Column

_               Redundant Row
1               First Row
```

After `dataTable.Rows[0].Delete();` executes:

```
First Column    Second Column

1               First Row
```

I hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

My headerRemoveButton function:

private void headerRowDeletebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

System.Data.DataTable dt = tableCollection[cboSheet.SelectedItem.ToString()];

```
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; i++)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1[i, 0].Value.ToString());
            dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText = dataGridView1[i,0].Value.ToString();
        }

        dt.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**